# Kohana, i18n for fuzzy_span

Tags: internationalization, kohana

How to translate text returned from Date::fuzzy_span that is used in Kohana 3.3.1? from

> "a couple of days ago"
>
> "less than a week ago"

to another language using i18n files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all possible strings from the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Date#fuzzy_span) in a translation file.

Next you only have to do something like this.

```
echo __(Date::fuzzy_span(time() + 20));
```